# Filter array of objects based on values in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects that I'd like to filter to create a new array based on whether or not the value of any key matches any value in another array.

```
const array1 = [{name: 'pink', id: 13}, {name: 'orange', id: 17}, {name: 'red, id: 64}, {name: 'purple', id: 47}, {name: 'yellow', id: 23}, {name: 'gray', id: 2}, {name: 'black', id: 200}, {name: 'violet', id: 4}]

const array2 = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink']
```

I've tried using a for...of loop inside of a return function but that is giving me errors.

```
    const array3 = array1.filter(color => {
        for (mainColor of array2){
            return color.name === mainColor 
        }
    });
```

This works but is clearly not the best way.

```
    const array3 = array1.filter(color => {
            return (color.main === 'red') || (color.main === 'blue')
        });
```

How can I get a third array from array1 that contains only the objects where the array1.name matches a value in array2?

Is it possible with ES6 or Lodash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop you're using, not a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: oops you're right, updated! still doesn't work though.

Comment: It does not work, because you are using `return` inside the loop, thus iterating only over the first element before exiting. If you want to use a `for` loop, you have to check whether the condition is `true` and return `true` only then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there, instead of for-loop use `includes` and **`return`**

```
const array3 = array1.filter(color => {
    return array2.includes ( color.name );
});
```

Or

```
const array3 = array1.filter( color => array2.includes ( color.name ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me give an alternative, that has slightly more code, but is more efficient as well, as it only needs to scan `array2` once:

```js
const array1 = [{name: 'pink', id: 13}, {name: 'orange', id: 17}, {name: 'red', id: 64}, {name: 'purple', id: 47}, {name: 'yellow', id: 23}, {name: 'gray', id: 2}, {name: 'black', id: 200}, {name: 'violet', id: 4}],
      array2 = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];

const colorSet = new Set(array2),
      array3 = array1.filter(color => colorSet.has(color.name));

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Do you think is worth it a previous process with `new Set(...)` just to check if a color exists in `array2`?  Just to remove the repeated? or Set has a better algorithm?

Comment: The `has` method works in constant time, while `includes` or `indexOf` need linear time, so when that is in a loop, you get *O(n²)* time complexity, while with a set you'll just have *O(n)* both for the `new Set` and the loop, and *O(n)+O(n)* is still *O(n)*. Of course, all this is not very relevant when we speak of an array that has a limited number of entries, not hundreds of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with Array's `includes()`:

```js
const array1 = [{name: 'pink', id: 13}, {name: 'orange', id: 17}, {name: 'red', id: 64}, {name: 'purple', id: 47}, {name: 'yellow', id: 23}, {name: 'gray', id: 2}, {name: 'black', id: 200}, {name: 'violet', id: 4}]

const array2 = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];

const array3 = array1.filter(color => array2.includes(color.name));

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` method already iterates on each item. You just have to `return` `true` if the element is present in the second array (by using `indexOf` or `includes`)

```js
const array1 = [{name: 'pink', id: 13}, {name: 'orange', id: 17}, {name: 'red', id: 64}, {name: 'purple', id: 47}, {name: 'yellow', id: 23}, {name: 'gray', id: 2}, {name: 'black', id: 200}, {name: 'violet', id: 4}]

const array2 = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];

let filteredArray = array1.filter(e => array2.indexOf(e.name) > -1);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know `indexOf` might seem a little outfashioned and ES5-ish, but it still does the job:

```js
const array1 = [{name: 'pink', id: 13}, {name: 'orange', id: 17}, {name: 'red', id: 64}, {name: 'purple', id: 47}, {name: 'yellow', id: 23}, {name: 'gray', id: 2}, {name: 'black', id: 200}, {name: 'violet', id: 4}],
  array2 = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];

let array3 = array1.filter(x => array2.indexOf(x.name) != -1)
console.log(array3)
```